# Clean URL in Joomla for internal links

Tags: url, joomla

I need clean urls for my internal links.
When clicked it displays the id of the particular article( eg id=65).
I want the url to display the name of the article or an alias name.
Thanks.

Comment: did you enable SEF url option from config ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a menu and store your articles in there, then give the menu items an alias. Then you can link using your menu items and your pages will have a clean URL.

You could also look at this extension: sh404SEF. It rewrites joomla URL's to a user-friendly format. (http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/sef/10134)